# Update module menu link location

Tags: 8, navigation

I have a custom module on a Drupal 8 site which has a controller defined with a menu item placed in the main menu.

I would now like to move the menu item from the main menu to a different menu.  I have tried changing the **menu_name** item in **modulename.links.menu.yml** rebuilding the routers and clearing the cache, but the menu item doesn't change to the different menu.

This is the modules *.links.menu.yml:

```
  events_register.events_register_form:
  title: 'Register'
  menu_name: main
  route_name: events_register.events_register_form
```

I changed the menu name to:

```
  events_register.events_register_form:
  title: 'Register'
  menu_name: footer
  route_name: events_register.events_register_form
```

How do I get my menu item to change menu? Is there an extra step I am missing?

Comment: Check your config for a menu_links_overrides file. It may be that the menu item is overridden to be in main.

Comment: You are correct about the menu_links_overrides file.  I removed the entry from the config file.  Cleared caches, rebuilt routes; but it was still in the original main menu.  However when I reset the item, it then moves to the defined area in the module yml file.
So I think I would have to write a module hook_update and reset the links there in order to do it all programatically.